HTML pre-processor for build configuration
We have an application with a browser based UI using HTML and javascript. The customer now wants a "production" build with a couple of purely development pages, and the buttons linking to them, removed.
I want a simple method to run a pre-processor over some of the HTML files in order to generate different versions at build time. E.g. have the HTML file look something like:
<td>
    {{DEV_BUILD}}<nav-button label="Widget test" url="widget_test.html">{{/DEV_BUILD}}
</td>

And then in my CMakeLists.txt do something like:
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/html/${FILE_NAME}"
    COMMAND html_preprocess -s "DEV_BUILD" "${HTML_FILE}" "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/html/${FILE_NAME}"
    DEPENDS "${HTML_FILE}"
    POST_BUILD
)

I could write my own bash script based on sed to do this, but was hoping that there would be something already out there that would save me some time.
I want something simple and lightweight. I have interacted in passing with YAML and Ruby on rails in the past and I found it a bit opaque.
